# UART connection between STM32 and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, stm32, uart, usart

i'm trying to establish an UART connection between STM32F4 and Raspberry Pi 3 to send motion sensor data.

STM32 C code:

```
    /* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f4_discovery.h"

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
int8_t polje[4];

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

void delay(uint32_t delay) {
    while(delay--);
}


// write to SPI1
void SPI1_Write(int8_t data)
{
  // short delay
  volatile int d = 500;
  while(d--);

  while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) == RESET){}
  SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1, data);

  while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET){}
  SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
}

// read from SPI1
int8_t SPI1_Read()
{
  // short delay
  volatile int d = 500;
  while(d--);

  while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) == RESET){}
  SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1, 0x00);

  while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET){}
  return SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
}

void initSPI1(void)
{
  // RCC

  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1, ENABLE);
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

  // PA5, PA6, PA7 for MISO, MOSI, and SCLK
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource5, GPIO_AF_SPI1);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_SPI1);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_SPI1);

  // SPI1 INIT
  SPI_InitTypeDef spi;
  spi.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
  spi.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
  spi.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b;
  spi.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
  spi.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_1Edge;
  spi.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
  spi.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_4;
  spi.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
  spi.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
  SPI_Init(SPI1, &spi);
  // SPI1 ENABLE
  SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);
}

void initMotionSensor()
{
  // RCC
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOE, ENABLE);

  // PE3 for slave select

  GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);
  // configure and start sensor
  GPIO_InitTypeDef ss;
  ss.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_3;
  ss.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  ss.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  ss.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  ss.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &ss);
  GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);

  // Aktiviram slave
  //delay(500);
  GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);
  // Zapisem inicializacijo senzorja
  // Zapisem 0x47 na naslov 0x20
  SPI1_Write(0x20);
  SPI1_Write(0x47);
  GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);
  //delay(500);
}

void initUSART1()
{
  // RCC
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART1, ENABLE);
  // USART1 init
  USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStruct;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_BaudRate = 9600;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Tx | USART_Mode_Rx;
  USART_Init(USART1, &USART_InitStruct);

  // USART1 enable
  USART_Cmd(USART1, ENABLE);

  // PB6 and PB7 for USART1 Tx and Rx
  GPIO_InitTypeDef usart_dev;
  usart_dev.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7;
  usart_dev.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  usart_dev.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  usart_dev.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  usart_dev.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &usart_dev);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource6,GPIO_AF_USART1);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource7,GPIO_AF_USART1);

}

void initDMA2()
{
  // RCC
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);
  // init DMA2
  DMA_InitTypeDef DMA_InitStructure;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_4;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_MemoryToPeripheral;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t) polje;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 4;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t) &(USART1 -> DR);
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_Medium;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_1QuarterFull;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
  DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream7, &DMA_InitStructure);
  // enable USART1 DMA Tx
  USART_DMACmd(USART1, USART_DMAReq_Tx, ENABLE);

  // enable DMA2 stream
  DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream7, ENABLE);
}      

/**
  * @brief   Main program
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
    // led init
    GPIO_InitTypeDef leds;
    leds.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15;
    leds.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    leds.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    leds.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    leds.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &leds);

  // SPI1
  initSPI1();

  // LIS motion sensor
  initMotionSensor();

  // USART1
  initUSART1();

  // DMA2
  initDMA2();

  while (1)
  {



    // read x1
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);
    SPI1_Write(0x29 | 0x80);
    volatile int8_t x1 = SPI1_Read();
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);
     delay(500);


    // read y1
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);
    SPI1_Write(0x2B | 0x80);
    volatile int8_t y1 = SPI1_Read();
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);

    if (x1 < -5) {
            // Vklopi ledico
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_12);
            delay(500);
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_12);
    }

    if (x1 > 5) {
            // Vklopi drugo ledico
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_14);
            delay(500);
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_14);
    }

    if (y1 < -5) {
            // Vklopi ledico
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_15);
            delay(500);
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_15);
    }

    if (y1 > 5) {
            // Vklopi drugo ledico
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_13);
            delay(500);
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_13);
    }

    delay(500);

    // read x
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);
    SPI1_Write(0x29 | 0x80);
    volatile int8_t x2 = SPI1_Read();
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);

     delay(500);

    // read y
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);
    SPI1_Write(0x2B | 0x80);
    volatile int8_t y2 = SPI1_Read();
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_3);
     delay(500);
    polje[0] = x1;
    polje[1] = x2;
    polje[2] = y1;
    polje[3] = y2;
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

Raspberry Pi code:

```
import time
import ctypes
import serial
import sys
from binascii import hexlify

ser = serial.Serial(

    port='/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1,
    dsrdtr=False
)
counter = 0

if (ser.isOpen() == False):
        ser.open()

#Flush before receiving or sending any data
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

while 1:
    x = ser.read()
    print (hexlify(x))
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

I already enabled the serial port interface on Raspberry Pi and disabled the terminal over serial option. I'm sure that the code on STM32 works, because I tried it with another STM32 as a receiver. I connected 2 GND pins together and STM32's Tx (PB6 in my case) to RasPi Rx (GPIO15). As an output i'm getting some numbers, but they don't change when I accelerate STM32 (the difference is seen on livewatch). I'm getting strange output on RasPi even if unplug the Tx - Rx connection.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it may be the cause, but when I was doing the same work I used `/dev/ttyAMA0` on Raspberry Pi 3. So check UART on this side of your system.

I disable Bluetooth so PIN 14/15 can now operate as UART TX/RX. This lead to that `/dev/ttyAMA0` now start operates as UART port, and not `/dev/ttyS0`.
[image]
See more on [official site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md).

This is my sample code for Raspberry (simplified):

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.timeout = 60  # 1 min
ser.open()

msg = ''
while True:
    char = ser.read(1)  # 1 byte
    msg = msg+char.decode('utf-8')
    if char == b'\r':
        break
```

And there for STM32F031K6:

**usart.c:**

```
...
huart1.Instance = USART1;
huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
...
```

**main.c:**

```
...
MX_USART1_UART_Init();

uint8_t str[STR_SIZE];
str_len = sprintf(str, "some message\r");
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, str, (uint32_t)str_len, 0xFFFF);
...
```

Comment: you sure it is /dev/ttyAMA0 and not /dev/ttyACM0? Did you use any level shifter or directly connected the TX and Rx?Did you coonnect the GND of Rpi3 to that of STM32?

Comment: @Raulp Yes, on my Raspberry Pi it's a `/dev/ttyAMA0` and not `/dev/ttyACM0`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev | grep ACM0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev | grep AMA0
ttyAMA0
```

We don't need to apply level shifter if both of our devices have the same logic voltage (3.3V in our case). And you need to connect GNDs for sure (probably you don't need to do that if the same power supply is used for both devices but it's always a good practice to explicitly connect GND).